# How to order an array of character according to the numbers that it contains

Tags: r, arrays, character

I would like to order the following vector of `chr`:

```
x=c("class 1", "class 2", "class 4", "class 7", "class 5", "class 3", "class 6",
"class 10", "class 9", "class 11", "class 8", "class 12", "class 21")
```

according to the numbers that appear in the characters. E.g., in this case, the desired result is:

```
class 1, class 2, class 3, class 4, class 5, class 6, class 7, class 8, class 9, class 10, class 11
class 12, class 21
```

I tried with:

```
x[order(x)]
```

but obtaining a different result:

```
> x[order(x)]
 [1] "class 1"  "class 10" "class 11" "class 12" "class 2"  "class 21" "class 3" 
 [8] "class 4"  "class 5"  "class 6"  "class 7"  "class 8"  "class 9"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, it is sorting alphabetically, and not considering the numeric value contained within the string.

There are a number of options to address this:

```
library(stringr)

str_sort(x, numeric = TRUE)
[1] "class 1"  "class 2"  "class 3"  "class 4"  "class 5"  "class 6"  "class 7"  "class 8"  "class 9"  "class 10" "class 11" "class 12" "class 21"
```

Or

```
library(gtools)

mixedsort(x)
[1] "class 1"  "class 2"  "class 3"  "class 4"  "class 5"  "class 6"  "class 7"  "class 8"  "class 9"  "class 10" "class 11" "class 12" "class 21"
```

Or without using another package, strip away "class" and use the numeric result to sort:

```
values <- as.numeric(gsub("class", "", x))
x[order(values)]
[1] "class 1"  "class 2"  "class 3"  "class 4"  "class 5"  "class 6"  "class 7"  "class 8"  "class 9"  "class 10" "class 11" "class 12" "class 21"
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because x is a vector of class "character" and elements (strings) are ordered alphabetically. Extract number from the strings an convert them to numeric type

```
y <- as.integer(substr(x, 7,8))
# y has the same order that x
# sort integers (numeric order) and match positions of unordered intergers
# match returns indexes of y ordered by sort(y)
x[match(y, sort(y))]
# Output is:
# [1] "class 1"  "class 2"  "class 7"  "class 6"  "class 5"  "class 4"  "class 3"  "class 11" "class 9"  "class 8"  "class 10" "class 12"
# [13] "class 21"
```